# How to transfer applescript dictation commands to another mac

Tags: mac, applescript, voice-dictation

I have created a set of dictation commands in AppleScript. Now I want to move them to another computer. How can I do that?

The dictation commands created by Automator at do not seem to exist as files that I can find a copy. I don't know where they are.

In fact, when I open Automator I do not see the dictation commands that I have previously written.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: First you said "_I have created a set of dictation commands in AppleScript_" then you said "_The dictation commands created by Automator..._", so which is it? Also what does a _dictation command_ look like in AppleScript? Have you tried searching by a unique or keyword that's within the _script_? If you did this in Automator, did you do this as a Workflow, Application or Service? If Workflow or Service, have you searched for files ending in `.workflow` (which is used by both of those types)?

Comment: Usually custom dict commands are either stored to ~/Library/Speech/Speakable Items/ (user) or /Library/Speech/Speakable Items/ (system wide)

Answer (score 1):

Custom user commands created for Enhanced Dictation, either directly in System Preferences > Accessibility > Dictation Commands or via Automator, are stored in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.recognition.AppleSpeechRecognition.CustomCommands.plist. If you haven't already custom commands on the new system, you can copy the entire file; otherwise, you'll need to manually move the entries by hand.